# Django model migration added two unwanted fields when using AbstractBaseUser class

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Django 1.9
Python 3.4

I created a custom Users model using AbstractBaseUser class. Below is the code.

```
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    # custom user class
    SYSTEM = 0
    TENANT = 1
    parent_type_choices = (
                           (SYSTEM, 'System'),
                           (TENANT, 'Tenant')
                           )
    sys_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False)
    parent_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=parent_type_choices, null=False, blank=False)
    parent_sys_id = models.ForeignKey('tenant.TenantModel', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=40)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    authentication_method = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    access_valid_start = models.DateTimeField()
    access_valid_end = models.DateTimeField()
    created_when = models.DateTimeField()
    created_by = models.BigIntegerField()
    last_updated_when = models.DateTimeField()
    last_updated_by = models.BigIntegerField()
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=2048)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "login"

    class Meta:
        app_label = "accounts"
        db_table = "Users"
```

When I migrated the changes, table was created in db with two extra fields which I didn't defined. `Password` and `last_login` were added.

```
desc Users;
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| password              | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_login            | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sys_id                | bigint(20)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| parent_type           | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name             | varchar(40)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name            | varchar(40)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| display_name          | varchar(80)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| login                 | varchar(40)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| authentication_method | varchar(80)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| pwd                   | varchar(40)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| access_valid_start    | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| access_valid_end      | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_when          | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_by            | bigint(20)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_updated_when     | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_updated_by       | bigint(20)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| notes                 | varchar(2048)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| parent_sys_id_id      | bigint(20)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Why this happened? How to remove these fields?

Comment: These are defined on AbstractBaseUser. Why don't you want them?

Comment: because I have defined my own password  field.

Comment: But *why*? Defining your own password field is an **extremely** bad idea; you bypass all of the password hashing and security features that Django provides you. Unless you have a really good reason, you must not do this.

Comment: Ok. So I should use the parent class's password field.

Comment: can I override this field to increase, decrease max_length?

Comment: Yes but again there is no need to do that. The password will be hashed, it will have a consistent length that is unrelated to the actual length of the original string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122977/discussion-between-user42-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score 0):

You inherited from `AbstractBaseUser` class which provides these fields. You can not remove them. Check [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) for more info